# Why the answer is wrong even though the output is the same?

Tags: c++, uri

There are many sites that provide solutions. I've seen them but they seemed very critical also time-consuming. So I tried to do it my own way. The output was correct but still, the URI site is saying that it's a wrong answer. I am a beginner in C++. Please help me with this. Here is the code and the problem:

#### URI Problem 1061

[image: URI Problem 1061]

#### code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string t;
    int day_i, day_f, hour_i, hour_f, min_i, min_f, sec_i, sec_f, hour, minute, sec, day;
    cin >> t >> day_i;
    cin >> hour_i >> t >> min_i >> t >> sec_i;
    cin >> t >> day_f;
    cin >> hour_f >> t >> min_f >> t >> sec_f;

    if (hour_f < hour_i) {
        hour_f = hour_f + 24;
    } else if (min_f < min_i) {
        min_f = min_f + 60;
    } else if (sec_f < sec_i) {
        sec_f = sec_f + 60;
    }

    hour = hour_f - hour_i;
    minute = min_f - min_i;
    sec = sec_f - sec_i;
    day = (day_f - day_i) - 1;

    cout << day << " dia(s)" << endl;
    cout << hour << " hora(s)" << endl;
    cout << minute << " minuto(s)" << endl;
    cout << sec << " segundo(s)" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are not correctly reading the input. There are some `:` in the example input

Comment: `sec_f += 60;` should probably be followed by `min_f -= 1;` (same for other conversion). your if chain seems to miss case whereas several condition happens.

Comment: With `Day 5 00:00:00` to `Day 6 00:00:00`, you print `0 dia(s)`...

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for pointing out the flaws of the code. I'll try again with proper conditions.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 for ":" there is a string "t"

Comment: `Day 5 23:58:58` to `Day 6 00:00:00` is also an interesting test input.

Comment: oh right, I didnt see that. Please include an example input and output in the question. Which test cases did you try? (I wanted to try the example test case from your link, but I cannot copy from the image into the input, please include text as text, not as images)

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah. Minutes and Seconds are coming in negative numbers.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I tired the input given in the problem. (From now on I'll put the input and output in the question which I tried. Thank you.)

Comment: Create `class Date` might help to structure the code.